# EMV: Second Generate AC Results in 6985 SW_Error Access condition not satisfied

Tags: payment, credit-card, emv, mastercard

I'm doing some EMV testing, and hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm seeing. I'm running the Mastercard M-TIP tests that apply to our solution, and I'm seeing some unexpected results. When running the M-TIP 50 tests (1, 2, 3) with the M-TIP 50 test card, I'm getting errors on the 2nd GENERATE_AC command. Our solution is technically defined as offline with online capability, but we're currently testing in an entirely offline environment.

I've spent a good amount of time reading the EMV books and scouring Google, but I still don't understand why it's returning 6985. The best guess I can come up with at this point is it has something to do with CDA (which should also be happening during this process?)

I've included the 1st and 2nd GEN_AC requests and responses to show what's happening. If someone could provide insight into what's happening or what's going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

```
    1st Generate AC (ARQC)
  Request : 80 AE 90 00 2F 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 08 26 17 01 03 00 B0 32 0F C0 22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 03 02 16 11 12 60 00 80
    Class    :80
    Ins      :AE
    P1       :90
    P2       :00
    Lc       :2F
    Data     :00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 08 26 17 01 03 00 B0 32 0F C0 22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 03 02 16 11 12 60 00 80
      Tag 9F 02: Transaction Amount                                             : 00 00 00 00 20 00
        Amount value: 20.00
      Tag 9F 03: Cashback Amount                                                : 00 00 00 00 00 00
        Amount value: 0.00
      Tag 95   : Terminal Verification Results (TVR)                            : 00 80 00 80 00
        Byte 1 bit 8   = 0      Offline data authentication was performed
               bit 7   = 0      SDA passed or not performed
               bit 6   = 0      No ICC data missing
               bit 5   = 0      Card does not appear on terminal exception file
               bit 4   = 0      DDA passed or not performed
               bit 3   = 0      CDA passed or not performed
               bit 2   = 0      SDA not selected
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 2 bit 8   = 1      ICC and terminal have different application versions
               bit 7   = 0      No Expired application
               bit 6   = 0      Application effective
               bit 5   = 0      Requested service allowed for card product
               bit 4   = 0      No New card
               bit 3   = 0      RFU
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 3 bit 8   = 0      Cardholder verification was successful or not performed
               bit 7   = 0      Recognised CVM
               bit 6   = 0      PIN Try Limit not exceeded
               bit 5   = 0      No PIN entry required (PIN pad may or may not be present or may or may not be working)
               bit 4   = 0      No PIN entry required (PIN pad may or may not be present)
               bit 3   = 0      No Online PIN entered
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 4 bit 8   = 1      Transaction exceeds floor limit
               bit 7   = 0      Lower consecutive offline limit not exceeded
               bit 6   = 0      Upper consecutive offline limit not exceeded
               bit 5   = 0      Transaction not selected randomly for online processing
               bit 4   = 0      Merchant did not force transaction online
               bit 3   = 0      RFU
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 5 bit 8   = 0      No Default TDOL used
               bit 7   = 0      Issuer authentication passed or not performed
               bit 6   = 0      Script processing passed before final GENERATE AC or no script received
               bit 5   = 0      Script processing passed after final GENERATE AC or no script received
               bit 4   = 0      RFU
               bit 3   = 0      RFU
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
      Tag 5F 2A: Transaction Currency Code                                      : 08 26
        Code (num) = 08 26
        Code (an)  = GBP
        Currency   = Pound Sterling
      Tag 9A   : Transaction Date                                               : 17 01 03
        Year : 2017
        Month: January
        Day  : 03
      Tag 9C   : Transaction Type                                               : 00
        Purchase (of goods or services)
      Tag 9F 37: Unpredictable Number                                           : B0 32 0F C0
      Tag 9F 35: Terminal Type                                                  : 22
        Terminal Type: 22
        Attended
        Merchant
        Offline with online capability
      Tag 9F 45: Data Authentication Code                                       : 00 00
      Tag 9F 4C: ICC Dynamic Number                                             : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
      Tag 9F 34: Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results                   : 44 03 02
        Byte 1 bit 8  = 0      (default value)
               bit 7  = 1      (Apply succeeding CVM field if this CVM is unsuccessful)
               bit 6-1= 000100 (Enciphered PIN verification performed by ICC)
        Byte 2        = '03'   (If terminal supports the CVM type)
        Byte 3        = '02'   (Successful)
      Tag 9F 21: Transaction Time                                               : 16 11 12
        Time         = 16:11:12
        Hours   (HH) = 16
        Minutes (MM) = 11
        Seconds (SS) = 12
      Tag 9F 40: Additional Terminal Capabilities                               : 60 00 80
        Byte 1 bit 8 = 0      Cash NOT supported
               bit 7 = 1      Goods supported
               bit 6 = 1      Services supported
               bit 5 = 0      CashBack NOT supported
               bit 4 = 0      Inquiry NOT supported
               bit 3 = 0      Transfer NOT supported
               bit 2 = 0      Payment NOT supported
               bit 1 = 0      Administrative NOT supported
        Byte 2 bit 8 = 0      CashBack Deposit NOT supported
               bit 7 = 0      RFU
               bit 6 = 0      RFU
               bit 5 = 0      RFU
               bit 4 = 0      RFU
               bit 3 = 0      RFU
               bit 2 = 0      RFU
               bit 1 = 0      RFU
        Byte 3 bit 8 = 1      Numeric keys supported
               bit 7 = 0      Alphabetic and special characters keys NOT supported
               bit 6 = 0      Command keys NOT supported
               bit 5 = 0      Function keys NOT supported
               bit 4 = 0      RFU
               bit 3 = 0      RFU
               bit 2 = 0      RFU
               bit 1 = 0      RFU
        Byte 4 bit 8 = 0      Print, attendant NOT supported
               bit 7 = 0      Print, cardholder NOT supported
               bit 6 = 0      Display, attendant NOT supported
               bit 5 = 0      Display, cardholder NOT supported
               bit 4 = 0      RFU
               bit 3 = 0      RFU
               bit 2 = 0      Code table 10 NOT supported
               bit 1 = 0      Code table 9 NOT supported
        Byte 5 bit 8 = 0      Code table 8 NOT supported
               bit 7 = 0      Code table 7 NOT supported
               bit 6 = 0      Code table 6 NOT supported
               bit 5 = 0      Code table 5 NOT supported
               bit 4 = 0      Code table 4 NOT supported
               bit 3 = 0      Code table 3 NOT supported
               bit 2 = 0      Code table 2 NOT supported
               bit 1 = 0      Code table 1 NOT supported
  masterKeyAC: 9E 15 20 43 13 F7 31 8A CB 79 B9 0B D9 86 AD 29
  uniqueKeyAC: 80 32 AD CE E0 B9 40 BA FB E3 5B 5B 15 9E 8F EA
  MCHIP SKD Session Key Derivation
    ATC:                             00 08
    UN:                              B0 32 0F C0
    Cryptogram Version No.:          10
    ICC Master Key AC:               9E 15 20 43 13 F7 31 8A CB 79 B9 0B D9 86 AD 29
    Derived Card Unique Key:         80 32 AD CE E0 B9 40 BA FB E3 5B 5B 15 9E 8F EA
    Derived Session Key:             A1 00 11 56 78 15 15 85 2B 53 76 A9 18 14 AA F2
  AC calculation: 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 08 26 17 01 03 00 B0 32 0F C0 79 00 00 08 A7 40 0F 04 00 00 80
    Amount Authorised                      : 00 00 00 00 20 00
    Amount Other                           : 00 00 00 00 00 00
    Terminal Verification Results          : 00 80 00 80 00
    Transaction Currency Code              : 08 26
    Transaction Date                       : 17 01 03
    Transaction Type                       : 00
    Unpredictable Number                   : B0 32 0F C0
    Application Interchange Profile        : 79 00
    Application Transaction Counter        : 00 08
    Card Verification Results              : A7 40 0F 04 00 00
    AC Session Key                         : A1 00 11 56 78 15 15 85 2B 53 76 A9 18 14 AA F2
  CDA Signature Generation
    Input data:                       E0 B8 C8 03 72 22 60 00 80 30 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 08 26 17 01 03 00 B0 32 0F C0 22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 03 02 16 11 12 60 00 80 9F 27 01 80 9F 36 02 00 08 9F 10 12 02 10 A7 40 0F 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
    ICC dynamic number:               98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A
    ICC private key:                  1A C2 53 A6 2F FC 28 F2 CA 67 EE 9B 2C BE 16 C2 38 FB E3 C8 8B 28 4A 81 18 44 4B 6A BD 6F 68 FD F4 70 23 62 20 D1 4A 1A 11 6F E4 A8 5C 33 FE 1E 35 CD 9A 3F 48 44 13 64 A3 E9 50 58 ED 26 35 82 D3 6E FA 8E A4 EF EE A2 42 21 C5 4C 02 FB 5D C3 AE 17 97 8B D6 CE 6B 68 A2 4B 3B 13 C8 61 3A 2E 1E 0A 53 1B A1 71 AF 7E 1E FF 44 4B FF 72 50 03 89 F6 64 2F 0F 62 E4 9A 43 0C 6D F7 0C 07 EE 0D
    ICC public modulus:               A0 8D F5 E5 1F E8 F5 B0 BE 6F 97 A3 0C 74 88 8D 55 E7 56 B3 42 F1 BF 06 91 99 C4 80 70 9C 75 F3 BA A0 D4 4C C4 E7 BC 9C 68 9F 5B F2 29 37 F4 B5 42 D1 9D 7B B1 98 74 5B D7 77 E2 15 8E E5 41 12 8A 15 8E 73 6A 88 4B 82 C5 21 61 6E F0 6F 8D 26 7C 07 B1 EF 79 8A B5 77 AA A3 C6 DD 89 37 C9 B2 34 4C EC AD 5A B8 D5 29 BC AC A7 F9 EC EA DE 85 99 0F 1E 04 FE AE 9F A0 33 DF 69 12 68 F9 F2 D5
    Terminal unpredictable number:    B0 32 0F C0
    Signature:                        89 A6 C6 A0 AD 68 43 14 03 EE 4E 92 4B A8 CE B0 ED D9 F2 23 9A AB C9 90 D6 67 FD D5 B4 FF FC 98 99 AB 66 A7 10 0D 5B EB EE 36 7C 36 79 2D A2 A2 92 11 A2 0C 00 71 86 4B BE 20 BA 44 57 73 E5 0C 2D FB 17 AA DE 5C 85 8B 19 66 B8 F3 40 E0 00 EB BF 10 8B 1C AE 91 BD D0 DC 0C D3 D5 40 85 42 72 B0 E2 2F 30 D5 B5 EA 61 29 C9 9F 4F 39 F3 EE BC 66 06 F7 60 11 4D D6 DB 57 CF 57 F6 C1 EF 8C 35
    Signed Dynamic Authentication Data
      Evaluated:          6A 05 01 26 08 98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A 80 EC 19 0A DB E4 1C 90 B0 AA 00 A2 EC B5 50 A9 54 A9 92 00 1E CA 05 21 B1 DD 13 98 ED BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB 8E 73 0F 77 06 61 76 D4 6A 68 EF 7A 9C 45 23 0C 9A 62 43 C6 BC
        RecoveredDataHeader                    '6A'h
        DynamicApplicationData_for_signature   '05 01 26 08 98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A 80 EC 19 0A DB E4 1C 90 B0 AA 00 A2 EC B5 50 A9 54 A9 92 00 1E CA 05 21 B1 DD 13 98 ED BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB'h structure
          SignedDataFormat         '05'h
          HashAlgorithmIndicator   '01'h
          ICCDynamicDataLength     38
          ICCDynamicData           '08 98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A 80 EC 19 0A DB E4 1C 90 B0 AA 00 A2 EC B5 50 A9 54 A9 92 00 1E CA 05 21 B1 DD 13 98 ED'h
          PadPattern               'BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB BB'h
        HashResult                             '8E 73 0F 77 06 61 76 D4 6A 68 EF 7A 9C 45 23 0C 9A 62 43 C6'h
        RecoveredDataTrailer                   'BC'h
      Expected:           6A 05 01 .. .. .. .. BC
        RecoveredDataHeader                    '6A'h
        DynamicApplicationData_for_signature   05 01 .. .. .. structure
          SignedDataFormat         '05'h
          HashAlgorithmIndicator   '01'h
          ICCDynamicDataLength     Length(ICCDynamicData)
          ICCDynamicData           .. concatenation
            QS{0-}
            ''h
          PadPattern               .. concatenation
            QS {..}
            ''h
        HashResult                             .. concatenation
          QS{1-}
          ''h
        RecoveredDataTrailer                   'BC'h
  Previous Transaction History
  Response: 61 A5
    SW1 SW2: 61 A5 (SW_OK Response bytes available(Le))
Get Response
  Request : 00 C0 00 00 A5
    Class    :00
    Ins      :C0
    P1       :00
    P2       :00
    Le       :A5
  Response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
    Ack Byte : C0
    Data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
      Tag 77   : Response Message Template Format 2                             
        Tag 9F 27: Cryptogram Information Data (CID)                              : 80
          Byte 1 bit 8-7 = 10     ARQC
                 bit 6-5 = 00     Payment System specific cryptogram
                 bit 4   = 0      No advice required
                 bit 3-1 = 000    No information given
        Tag 9F 36: Application Transaction Counter (ATC)                          : 00 08
          Decimal value = 8
        Tag 9F 4B: Signed Dynamic Application Data                                : 89 A6 C6 A0 AD 68 43 14 03 EE 4E 92 4B A8 CE B0 ED D9 F2 23 9A AB C9 90 D6 67 FD D5 B4 FF FC 98 99 AB 66 A7 10 0D 5B EB EE 36 7C 36 79 2D A2 A2 92 11 A2 0C 00 71 86 4B BE 20 BA 44 57 73 E5 0C 2D FB 17 AA DE 5C 85 8B 19 66 B8 F3 40 E0 00 EB BF 10 8B 1C AE 91 BD D0 DC 0C D3 D5 40 85 42 72 B0 E2 2F 30 D5 B5 EA 61 29 C9 9F 4F 39 F3 EE BC 66 06 F7 60 11 4D D6 DB 57 CF 57 F6 C1 EF 8C 35
        Tag 9F 10: Issuer Application Data [M/Chip 4]                             : 02 10 A7 40 0F 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
          Key Derivation Index      = 02
          Cryptogram Version Number = 10
          Card Verification Results (CVR)  = A7 40 0F 04 00 00
            Byte 1 bit 8-7 = 10     AC Returned in Second Generate AC: Not requested
                   bit 6-5 = 10     AC Returned in First Generate AC: ARQC
                   bit 4   = 0      RFU
                   bit 3   = 1      Offline PIN Verification Performed
                   bit 2   = 1      Offline Encrypted PIN Verification Performed
                   bit 1   = 1      Offline PIN Verification Successful
            Byte 2 bit 8   = 0      DDA not returned
                   bit 7   = 1      M/Chip Select 4: Combined DDA/AC Generation Returned in First Generate AC, M/Chip Lite 4: Value not allowed
                   bit 6   = 0      Combined DDA/AC Generation Not Returned in Second Generate AC
                   bit 5   = 0      Issuer Authentication not performed
                   bit 4   = 0      CIAC-Default not skipped on CAT3 or not required
                   bit 3   = 0      RFU
                   bit 2   = 0      RFU
                   bit 1   = 0      RFU
            Byte 3 bit 8-5 = 0000   Right nibble of Script Counter : '0'
                   bit 4-1 = 1111   Right nibble of PIN Try Counter: 'F'
            Byte 4 bit 8   = 0      RFU
                   bit 7   = 0      Unable To Go Online Not Indicated
                   bit 6   = 0      Offline PIN Verification Performed
                   bit 5   = 0      No Failure OF Offline PIN Verification
                   bit 4   = 0      PTL Not Exceeded
                   bit 3   = 1      International Transaction
                   bit 2   = 0      International Transaction
                   bit 1   = 0      Terminal Does Not Erroneously Consider Offline PIN OK
            Byte 5 bit 8   = 0      Lower Consecutive Offline Limit Not Exceeded
                   bit 7   = 0      Upper Consecutive Offline Limit Not Exceeded
                   bit 6   = 0      Lower Cumulative Offline Limit Not Exceeded
                   bit 5   = 0      Upper Cumulative Offline Limit Not Exceeded
                   bit 4   = 0      Go Online On Next Transaction Was Not Set (in this transaction or in a previous one)
                   bit 3   = 0      No Issuer Authentication Failed (in this transaction or in a previous one)
                   bit 2   = 0      No Script Received (in a previous transaction)
                   bit 1   = 0      No Script Failed (in a previous transaction)
            Byte 6 bit 8   = 0      RFU
                   bit 7   = 0      RFU
                   bit 6   = 0      RFU
                   bit 5   = 0      RFU
                   bit 4   = 0      RFU
                   bit 3   = 0      RFU
                   bit 2   = 0      No Match found in Additional Check Table
                   bit 1   = 0      Match Found in Additional Check Table
          DAC                       = 00 00
          Counters                  = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
    SW1 SW2  : 90 00 (SW_OK)
2nd Generate AC (TC)
  Request : 80 AE 50 00 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 59 33 00 80 00 80 00 B0 32 0F C0 98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A
    Class    :80
    Ins      :AE
    P1       :50
    P2       :00
    Lc       :23
    Data     :00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 59 33 00 80 00 80 00 B0 32 0F C0 98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A
      Tag 91   : Issuer Authentication Data [M/Chip]                            : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
      Tag 8A   : Authorization Response Code                                    : 59 33
        Response Code = 59 33
        Meaning       = Unable to go online, Requesting for offline approval
      Tag 95   : Terminal Verification Results (TVR)                            : 00 80 00 80 00
        Byte 1 bit 8   = 0      Offline data authentication was performed
               bit 7   = 0      SDA passed or not performed
               bit 6   = 0      No ICC data missing
               bit 5   = 0      Card does not appear on terminal exception file
               bit 4   = 0      DDA passed or not performed
               bit 3   = 0      CDA passed or not performed
               bit 2   = 0      SDA not selected
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 2 bit 8   = 1      ICC and terminal have different application versions
               bit 7   = 0      No Expired application
               bit 6   = 0      Application effective
               bit 5   = 0      Requested service allowed for card product
               bit 4   = 0      No New card
               bit 3   = 0      RFU
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 3 bit 8   = 0      Cardholder verification was successful or not performed
               bit 7   = 0      Recognised CVM
               bit 6   = 0      PIN Try Limit not exceeded
               bit 5   = 0      No PIN entry required (PIN pad may or may not be present or may or may not be working)
               bit 4   = 0      No PIN entry required (PIN pad may or may not be present)
               bit 3   = 0      No Online PIN entered
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 4 bit 8   = 1      Transaction exceeds floor limit
               bit 7   = 0      Lower consecutive offline limit not exceeded
               bit 6   = 0      Upper consecutive offline limit not exceeded
               bit 5   = 0      Transaction not selected randomly for online processing
               bit 4   = 0      Merchant did not force transaction online
               bit 3   = 0      RFU
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
        Byte 5 bit 8   = 0      No Default TDOL used
               bit 7   = 0      Issuer authentication passed or not performed
               bit 6   = 0      Script processing passed before final GENERATE AC or no script received
               bit 5   = 0      Script processing passed after final GENERATE AC or no script received
               bit 4   = 0      RFU
               bit 3   = 0      RFU
               bit 2   = 0      RFU
               bit 1   = 0      RFU
      Tag 9F 37: Unpredictable Number                                           : B0 32 0F C0
      Tag 9F 4C: ICC Dynamic Number                                             : 98 43 55 5A 0A C1 C2 4A
  Previous Transaction History
  Response: 69 85
    SW1 SW2: 69 85 (SW_Error Accesscondition not satisfied)
Test Completed
```

Comment: Have you read the reason behind 6985 at the time of Sec Gen AC?? EMV 4.2 book 2 says - The ICC shall permit at most two GENERATE AC commands in a transaction. If the terminal issues more than two, the third and all succeeding GENERATE AC commands shall end with SW1 SW2 = '6985', and no cryptogram shall be returned.

Comment: @Arjun, Yes, thanks, I did see that. However, looking at the log of the testing tool I'm using, I only see the first and second generation commands. There doesn't seem to be a third request that would cause the error. I've added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: This normally happens when the C-APDU is sent while card is in wrong state. Generate AC is expected in 'Initiated' and 'Online' states. But if by any chance the state has moved to 'Script', then it will give 'Conditions not satisfied' error. Can you look into this part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some help from my test tool's support system. Their response helped explain this scenario:

**Response 1:**
*"The transaction amount in your test cases M-TIP 50 test1, test2, and test 3 are all above the floor limit, so the transactions are supposed to go online. However, due to your test environment is offline, the transactions can not be processed online. I can see the issuer authentication data in the 2nd generate AC are all 0s (They are not returned by the issuer, but the default value set by the terminal). The card validate the authentication data to see if the data is returned by the issuer. In your case, the validation is failed and the card returns "69 85"."*

**Response 2:**
*"The MTIP50 test cases are a little special. The issuer authentication data for MTIP50 test cases is 16 bytes which is different than the normal value (10 bytes). Thus BTT has extra checks on the issuer authentication data of MTIP50. Since the issuer authentication data are all zeros in your case, the simulated card thinks they are not valid."*

**Resolution:**
Turns out this was an issue with the testing tool I was using. They recently released a new version of their software and this no longer happens.

Comment: If you go by MasterCard card spec what @alexander-vgn mentioned are the correct reasons. He has explained all cases which could lead this to your error.

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with the testing tool I was using. They recently released a new version of their software and this no longer happens.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you did a lot of "Offline approval" without clear counters.

There are several possible reasons in your case for 6985:

1) **AC Session Key Counter Limit Exceeded**
Because response code in Second Generate AC is "Unable to go online, Requesting for offline approval" card goes Offline, therefore CTR accumulates and is not reset (it reset only then Online in Generate AC 2).

Try to personalize increased limits or do full Online.

2) **Overflow during the amount conversion**, if transaction International
(transaction currency != CRM currency Code).
Required full Online

3) **Overflow during add the cumulative amount**, if transaction Domestic (transaction currency == CRM currency Code).
Required full Onlinе

also, check why "Country code" is absent in Cdol1